# Windows that were closed keep reappearing

Tags: xorg, lightdm, xfce, window-manager

Xubuntu 14.04. Some windows that were closed several days ago keep reappearing at random. I mean the active workspace is superposed by a picture of the window(s) before it was closed and when I click on it, it disappears.
These reappearing windows belong to Xubuntu terminal and Matlab.

Comment: Are you sure you're not minimising?

Comment: Yes I'm totally sure.

Comment: Are you changing workspaces?

Comment: Yeah I do but the windows were closed a while back.